# Como alterar o título de cada página PHP de forma dinâmica?

Tags: php, html

Não entendo quase nada de PHP. Certa vez um amigo me enviou um código que me permitia separar minha página em várias partes e depois pegar essas partes novamente para o caso de eu alterar algo nos scripts e folhas de estilo, então eu não preciso ir em página por página para alterar isso novamente, trata-se do `include_once` do PHP.

Enfim, lembro que alguma vez eu li um artigo que falava que é uma boa prática adicionar um *title* descritivo para cada página de nosso site, por exemplo "Meu site - Tutorial Photoshop".

Partindo dessas duas informações, eu me deparei com um problema. Separei meu site em duas partesm o header e o footer, e apenas altero o main com as informações que eu desejar:

```
<?php   
include_once "./includes/header.php";   
<!-- AQUI VAI MEU CONTEÚDO -->  
include_once "./includes/footer.php"; 
?>
```

Só que o `<title>` da página fica no header (que é padrão de todas as páginas), e acaba sendo único para o site todo. Pensando aqui em casa eu encontrei uma solução, que é usar o JavaScript para modificar o title. Eu tenho uma prática que é sempre colocar uma H1 com o assunto principal do site antes de começar o conteúdo, por exemplo `<h1>Contato</h1>`. A questão é, isso influencia em algo no site? Seja no SEO ou qualquer outra coisa? Existe alguma maneira melhor de faze-lo?

Este é o código que uso para mudar o título:

```
var title = $('main').first('h1').text();
$('title').text('Meu site -' + title);
```

Comment: Pode colocar aqui o código que está a usar para chamar/abrir novas páginas?

Comment: Acho que é isso que deseja não?
`<?php
 include_once "./includes/header.php";
 <!-- AQUI VAI MEU CONTEÚDO -->
 include_once "./includes/footer.php";
?>`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O ideal seria ter o título armazenado em uma variável no topo do PHP, e usar o valor dessa variável tanto no `<title>` quanto no `<h1>`.

Por exemplo, o código de uma página ficaria assim:

```
<?php
$titulo = "Meu site - Tutorial Photoshop";
include_once "./includes/header.php";   
?>

<h1><?php echo $titulo ?></h1>
etc.

<?php
include_once "./includes/footer.php"; 
?>
```

E o `header.php` conteria algo assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
...
   <title><?php echo $titulo ?></title>
...
```

Em termos de SEO, é sim preferível ter o `<title>` definido pelo PHP e não pelo JS, pois vários robôs de busca desconsideram JS.

Answer (score 5):

Uma outra forma interessante seria centralizar todo o trabalho no `header.php`, definindo os títulos de cada página usando um array, por exemplo:

```
$titulos = [
    'index.php' => 'Meu site - Tutorial Photoshop',
    'tutoriais.php' => 'Tutoriais de Photoshop - Meu Site',
    'ajuda.php' => 'Página de ajuda - Meu Site',
    'contato.php' => 'Fale Conosco - Meu Site'
    #pode ter 'n' páginas
];

#limpa a url (ex.: /url.php?foo#bar => url.php)
$uri = str_replace("/","",explode(".php",$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])[0]).".php";
```

E no título você coloca:

```
<h1><?php echo $titulos[$uri] ?></h1>
```

Basicamente o que o código faz é criar um "banco" com todos os títulos, e ele imprime o titulo atual de acordo com a URL que for detectada.

Desta forma seu código fica mais centralizado e facilita a manutenção.

Answer (score 0):

```
$titulos = [
    'index.php' => 'Meu site - Tutorial Photoshop',
    'tutoriais.php' => 'Tutoriais de Photoshop - Meu Site',
    'ajuda.php' => 'Página de ajuda - Meu Site',
    'contato.php' => 'Fale Conosco - Meu Site'
    #pode ter 'n' páginas
];
```

## limpa a url (ex.: /url.php?foo#bar => url.php)

```
$uri = str_replace("/","",explode(".php",$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])[0]).".php";
```

Você pode usar esse método acima, mas isso só funcionar se estiver na pasta raiz do projeto, se estiver testando no servidor em pasta escondida não terá resultado então troque 
`str_replace("/","",explode(".php",$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])[0]).".php";` por `end(explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));`, pois independente de onde esteja o projeto sempre retornará o nome do arquivo acessado.

Ficará assim:

```
$titulos = [
    'index.php' => 'Palestra Clube',
    'contato.php' => 'Contato',
    'sobre.php' => 'Sobre'
    #pode ter 'n' páginas
];

$uri = end(explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

## limpa a url (ex.: /url.php?foo#bar => url.php)

```
echo $titulos[$uri];
```

Comment: Olá @AlexandreFelix, uma dica, use as barras de formatação, isso auxilia muito o usuario ao ler sua resposta. Faça o tour para maiores duvidas http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour